Azure Guest API invalid Property "Sponsors"
The solution is ttying to invite guest users from Azure AD using web API, but most of the properties are able to added, but only the sponsor is not added DirectoryObject, this APP has the all User.ReadWrite all permissions, tried many ways, but not able to add, can any one help please.
An exception invalid property sponsor0
This is the code:
Sponsors = new List<DirectoryObject>
{

    new DirectoryObject
    {

         AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
         {

             {
                  "sponsors","testuser"
             }
         }

    }
}

I am expecting to invite a guest user with "sponsors" value from invitation payload to add sponsors in the guest users information.

The invitation resource in Microsoft Graph does not have a "sponsors" field directly, which is likely why you're encountering the "invalid property 'sponsors'" error.

"sponsors" is not a standard property, you need to define it using a custom extension in Azure AD. This will allow you to store the sponsor information as part of the user's profile.

To create an extension that stores the sponsors field, you can use Microsoft Graph to define the schema.
API request:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{application-id}/extensionProperties
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "sponsors",
  "dataType": "String",
  "targetObjects": [
    "User"
  ]
}


Once the custom extension is created, you can use it in the invitation process.

Here's how to add the "sponsors" information to the guest user's profile at the time of inviting them
var invitation = new Invitation
{
    InvitedUserEmailAddress = "guestuser@example.com",
    InviteRedirectUrl = "https://yourapp.com",
    SendInvitationMessage = true,
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        // Use the extension schema to add the sponsors value
        { "extension_{app-client-id}_sponsors", "SponsorUserNameOrID" }
    }
};

await graphClient.Invitations.Request().AddAsync(invitation);

Once the guest user is invited and added to Azure AD, we can retrieve or update the sponsor information via Microsoft Graph.
Retrieve User with Sponsors:
var user = await graphClient.Users["guestuser@example.com"]
    .Request()
    .Select("id,displayName,extension_{app-client-id}_sponsors")
    .GetAsync();

var sponsors = user.AdditionalData["extension_{app-client-id}_sponsors"];


Thanks for your quick response and for the solution, I am sure that will work.

@Suresh Chikkam
I have tried two different ways to fix the issue . the sponsor field is available in the guest information azure portal User option. I tried with the below code to add sponsor first time sending an invitation var invitationRequestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Invitation{
InvitedUserSponsors = new List(){new DirectoryObject
{OdataType = "microsoft.graph.user",
d = strSponsorID,
AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>(    }}},but this code cannot update the guest user , unfortunately, will keep you update

var invitationRequestBody = new icrosoft.Graph.Models.User
{ GivenName = firstName,
Surname = lastName,
JobTitle = jobTitle,
CompanyName = companyName,
Department = department,
Country = countryOrRegionProvince,
MobilePhone = mobilePhone,
UsageLocation = usageLocation,
Sponsors = new List { new DirectoryObject{ Id = strSponsorID,  OdataType = "microsoft.graph.user", AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>() {//dont know what to code here}}}}; var response = await graphClient.Users[id].PatchAsync(invitationRequestBody);

@Suresh Chikkam,
the above code is to update and add sponsor after an Invitation sent successfully
the method will execute after the below code

var invitationRequestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.Invitation
{
InvitedUserDisplayName = displayName,
InvitedUserEmailAddress = email,
InviteRedirectUrl = redirectUrl,
SendInvitationMessage = true,
InvitedUserType = AddUserConstants.Constants.GuestUser.ToString(),
Status = AddUserConstants.Constants.GuestStatus.ToString()
};
var invitationResponse = await graphClient.Invitations.PostAsync(invitationRequestBody);
}
